# Products are disappearing from admin and frontend

Tags: database, products, compiler

A client is having the issue of multiple products that have just disappeared from Magento, and they are having to re-enter all of the data. I ruled out CSV issues because they have never used this method for uploading products. Below are a few of the possibilities I will be trying, but someone here may have a more educated answer. I am trying:

**Clearing the compiler:** The compiler is disabled, but the state is compiled.

**Database size:** I will try clearing the log tables in the database, which is over 1.5GB in size.

**Reindex data:** I will try reindexing all of the data, but this shouldn't be the case.

I am worried that it could be database corruption, does anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: There is little information to go off of. My first guess would be that there may be a process that is deleting the products. There is no way to tell with out looking further.

Comment: Have you actually checked the products in the database? When you say disappearing from the backend, are you suggesting they do not show up in catalog -> manage products?

Answer (score 1):

Products don't disappear and clients often don't provide the full truth!

I love my customers, but its often the case that I don't get the full information when something is going wrong. So my advice would be to go back to the logs to see what they are up to.

- If the products are visible in the admin, then you know they still exist and you need to check things like stock settings, status, visibility, categories and website allocation.
- If the products aren't visible in the admin, they've been deleted.

The most common culprit for product oddities is when import/export tools are used (eg. Magmi/Rapidflow/API etc.) and the supplied data was incomplete/incorrect.

It should be easy enough to ascertain the cause, just check the basics above.

NB. There is no such thing as database corruption, it works or it doesn't. It won't randomly delete individual rows of data whilst still leaving the remainder of the website fully functional.

*Remember Dr. House had it right when he said patients always lie!*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, user error was also my first guess but I would have expected it to happen in CSV import or something of the sort. The client is using a tool called Stitch Labs to manage inventory across other channels like eBay (http://www.stitchlabs.com/magento-inventory-management). Could this be one of those import/export tools that would cause the issue?